# How to fix controller manager not loading on custom controller ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros-humble

I've been attempting to integrate my SolidWorks URDF file into a Gazebo simulation with ROS2 control. I've managed to successfully load my models into Gazebo and RViz2, but problems arise when try to load my custom controllers. I have tried following the solutions posted onto threads with the exact same problem as I have but to no avail. Here is my setup:

Github REPO (Go to src/testarm): [github](https://github.com/mikeyags1016/TestArmGit.git)

[image: Log 1]

[image: Log 2]

[image: Simulations after running]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please try to use text over screenshots as much as possible. For example, copy and paste the text instead of a screenshot of your terminal. Thanks for your kind cooperation. BTW, the error "No transform from ..." hints that some of the TF frames are unavailble. I suggest validating the exported URDF file.